# The same code produces different results in browser and localhost/phpmyadmin(database)

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I was making signin/signup form for my web application. Sign up worked fine up to now but later on sign_in form I was stuck.

My problem concerns to password matching between `sign_up` form and `sign_in` form and if password matches letting that valid user reach a private page.

Below code is from my `sign_up` form which handles the hashing of user's password

```
    $final_pswd = "Testgrg061";//I set a default password 
    //because i'm testing this code alone on browser to 
    //know exactly what output this code produce.

    $salt = 88888888; //This salt was also set default by me for only 
     //testing purposes.Ya I know we have to use a code which produce it randomly. 

    $encriptpass = hash('sha256', $final_pswd . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $encriptpass = hash('sha256', $encriptpass . $salt); 
        } 

    //It produce a password like below on $encriptpass variable in browser test!!
      $encriptpass = 2c19f750f242e16102553d3d749ab80fa93a736aa210c70e173a0207604c70c6
```

but using the same code and the same password, when I try to store password on database from `sign_up` form via localhost my password column gets a different hash value of the same password like below:

```
password - f0b3a1a382d1899453021f2dbae7c39cf2b547721bbb40d984c14deae7c7662f
```

Salt and password were the same... looping was also done in the same way... everything was the same just the browser test and localhost test brought some changes? And I have no idea what was going on here.

That's the reason the "username or password was invalid" error dialog box appears all the time when I try to sign_in. Most interesting thing was that when I edit my password column in database with that browser tested hash then every process works normal and I successfully enter on private page! I used a default salt value but the problem might be the same when I use some code to generate random salt value.

My `sign_in` code looks like:

```
$check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
{ 
    $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
} 

if($check_password === $row['password']) 
{
    // If they do, then we flip this to true 
    $success = true;//It was set false in above
}     
if(success){
    //creating session and private page concern codes
}
```

Above code grabs the normal password entered by user on sign_in form. `Row ['salt']` is the salt value retrieved from database salt column from that particular username entered by that user. After hashing and then adding salt and then looping this code did everything the same as `sign_up` code did. Finally during `$check_password === $row['password']` it doesn't match because of the problem described above (browser and localhost showing different output of same code).

Comment: Any reason that you are trying to reinvent the wheel instead of using http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: Do your form have any js validation/ hash ??

Comment: Share your form/ js and also both password strings, your saved one and one from user input through browser.

Comment: @e4c5 ok bro i will check that.

Comment: ya i have js validation but the problem doesn't concern to  js validation @SubinThomas bro.On my js validation I have just made a password be upper_case,lower_case,some character and number.If every things fine in client side validation then it ends there and then comes the hashing case in server side code.

Comment: And you do realize the huge burden of iterating for 65000 times with a heavy function like hash?

Comment: I have used on my code default password "Testgrg061" and salt "88888888"  to find out the output and got it.Again I used the same code default password and salt on my signup_form and signin_form but this time  signup_form is producing different result and the signin_form is producing like browser result.Ya, I forgot to say that signin_form code produces same output result as browsers test output result!

Comment: @e4c5 bro here i'm not trying to create a perfect strong hash leave that aside and please if you can find out the reason why browser output and localhost output appear to be different with the same code I will love to hear your answer.during storing time my output result becomes different but the signin time that code work as the same as browser tested one.

Comment: no like I said, stop reinventing the wheel and use the standard methods.

Comment: Need to check your JS validation, expected something in it.

Comment: @SubinThomas it will be out of topic I have checked all and the problem is concern to server code not client side.

Comment: for loop will always works same, hash also do the same. So our concern is only the difference in salt values, and difference in passwords comes from sign up or login.

Comment: So either your password is not matching -- need to verify it-- Can you echo $_POST['password'] for "Testgrg061"???

Comment: bro i used copy/paste too during my login time :( and i'm sure password was same Testgrg061 but some how during the step of storing password from above code I get a different value stored in my password column in database  and which isn't the same when my signin code check for normal password it hashes turns some thing same as browser tested but not same as localhost signup hash one.

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg Did you check what is the echo $_POST['password'] output??

Comment: @SubinThomas ya bro I just tried and it echo out Testgrg061 for $_POST['password'];

Comment: Now look into DB side. Insert and select commands please.

Comment: @SubinThomas bro I found my problem :D My program for making a hash password was like :- hash+user password+salt+loop :D but the variable which was holding the user password wasn't working and my hash were build without user password and only with hash+salt+loop :D so...there was difference between signup_form password and signin_form password because in signin_form my user password variable were in action I mean that variable worked there and it made the password hash+user password+salt+loop as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me, so I think the problem is with your stored values in mysql.

```
$final_pswd = "Testgrg061";//I set a default password
//because i'm testing this code alone on browser to
//know exactly what output this code produce.

$salt = 88888888; //This salt was also set default by me for only
//testing purposes.Ya I know we have to use a code which produce it randomly.

$encriptpass = hash('sha256', $final_pswd . $salt);
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
{
    $encriptpass = hash('sha256', $encriptpass . $salt);
}
echo $encriptpass.'<br />';



$check_password = hash('sha256', $final_pswd . $salt);
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
{
    $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $salt);
}
echo $check_password.'<br />';

if($check_password === $encriptpass)
{
    // If they do, then we flip this to true
    $success = true;//It was set false in above

}

var_dump($success);
```

$row['salt'] and $row['password'] are ok? The field named "password" is enough long?
And the $_POST['password'] contain Testgrg061?

Comment: bro ya $row['salt'] and $row['password'] are retrieving value from database correctly. The field name "password" on database is enough and my hash is sha256 which is 64bit hash and it is stored correctly.Ya i used the same password Testgrg061 for signup_form and signin_form but the result are different as I have already posted browser password and localhost password.